# C ++ undefined reference when inheriting from template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, undefined-reference

I have MapListDialog which inherits from base class ListView. But I have problem with "undefined reference to" by MapListDialog constructor definition.

```
//create instance in main.cpp
mapListDialog = new MapListDialog(this);
```

Definition for MapListDialog inherited from ListView

src/modes/MapListDialog.h

```
#include <controls/ListView.h>

class MapListItem { 
public:
    const char *label; 
};

class MapListDialog : public ListView<MapListItem> {
public:
    //***compiler fails at line below ***
    MapListDialog(BaseView *parent): ListView<MapListItem>(parent) {};
    ~MapListDialog() {};    
};
```

Definition of ListView

src/controls/ListView.h

```
#include "Dialog.h"

template<class T>
class ListView : public Dialog {
public:
    ListView(BaseView *parent);
    ~ListView();
};
```

src/controls/ListView.cpp

```
#include "ListView.h"

template<class T>
ListView<T>::ListView(BaseView *parent):Dialog(parent) {}

template<class T>
ListView<T>::~ListView() { }
```

I think, is not necessary put here definition of Dialog, but for every case...

```
class Dialog : public BaseView {
    Dialog(BaseView *parent);
    ~Dialog();
}

class BaseView {
public:
    BaseView(BaseView *parent);
    ~BaseView();
}
```

> MapListDialog.h:23: error: undefined reference to
>   'ListView::ListView(BaseView*)'

Comment: I'm suspecting you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/495056/1387438 (you didn't describe how code is split in files, but definition of methods outside class declaration suggest that problem).

Comment: ok so my guess was correct. Just move template to header file.

Comment: Thank you, now it compiles correctly. I will read better posts above